# linux package services installed checked by single line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, rpm

I want to check whether a specific Linux package has been installed or not using th  `rpm` command in a single line.
However , it's always giving me a positive result as service present, even if `httpd` is not installed, can you please point out issue here?

```
rpm -qa httpd && echo "service present" || echo " service not present"
```

Comment: I don't think `rpm` has a useful exit status, not with your code at least.

Comment: Try running `rpm -qa foo ; echo $?` , if the output is `0` then `&&` is useless in your code.

Comment: `package=$(rpm -q httpd); ((${#package})) && echo "service present"` There might be a better way but, there is your one-liner

Comment: @Jetchisel  This is not working as well, always getting service present as a result

Comment: Use an `if` clause/statement not that short circuit, that is a cause for electrocution... `if ((${#package})); then foo; else bar; fi`

Comment: Sorry, are you using Bash or sh? [They're not the same thing.](/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) Please [edit] and fix the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following by substituting the `<PACKAGE_NAME>`

#### Shorter

`rpm -q <PACKAGE_NAME> && echo "service present" || echo "service not present"`

#### Longer

`rpm -qa <PACKAGE_NAME> | grep <PACKAGE_NAME> && echo "service present" || echo "service not present"`

Example:

```bash
rpm -qa httpd | grep httpd && echo "service present" || echo "service not present"
```

```bash
# Output
[root@bfa3155b8feb /]# rpm -qa httpd | grep httpd && echo "service present" || echo "service not present"
service not present
```